# How I get a one row of elements from nested JSON in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

is there any SOL query in MariaDB to get a single row of JSON from nested JSON array

```
[
{"connection":[{"f_id":"593435068"}],"connection_id":1},
{"connection":[{"f_id":"1103648403"}],"connection_id":2}
]
```

I am trying to that:

if I add **1** in SQL query it will give me

```
{"connection":[{"f_id":"593435068"}],"connection_id":1}
```

if I add **2** in SQL query it will give me

```
{"connection":[{"f_id":"1103648403"}],"connection_id":2}
```

I did this successfully in MYSQL with the help of `JSON_TABLE()`
as :

```
SELECT jd.con_name,jd.con_id 
  FROM your_table,
  JSON_TABLE(json_col, "$[*]" 
  COLUMNS( con_name JSON PATH "$.connection", con_id JSON PATH "$.connection_id" ) ) AS jd 
 WHERE jd.con_id = 1;
```

This way i get always accurate row

but I am unable to do this in MariaDB

can anyone please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(js, '$[0]'), JSON_EXTRACT(js, '$[1]') 
  FROM your_table
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ca888b47ef44faa1777f1c1f9a288520)</kbd>

MariaDB has no `JSON_TABLE()` support yet.

Assume that you have another table(`t2`) holding ID values 1 and 2, then consider using :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(t1.js, CONCAT('$[', t2.ID - 1, ']')) AS col
  FROM t2
 CROSS JOIN t1
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b66deb9a6c64a8a23d4e27ff8ca8dcf6)</kbd>

Comment: this is the static method of getting JSON but I only know about Id = 1 or 2, I want to pass **id** to SQL query and get JSON row.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you handled in MySQL @GeeraSaini ?

Comment: In MYSQL I did: SELECT jd.con_name,jd.con_id FROM your_table,JSON_TABLE(json_col, "$[*]" COLUMNS( con_name JSON PATH "$.connection", con_id JSON PATH "$.connection_id" ) ) AS jd where jd.con_id = 1; This way i get always accurate row

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to use a combination of functions:

- [JSON_SEARCH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_search/)
- [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/)
- [CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat/)
- [JSON_EXTRACT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/)

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(`jd`.`con_json`, '$.connection') `con_name`,
  JSON_EXTRACT(`jd`.`con_json`, '$.connection_id') `con_id`,
  `jd`.`con_json`
FROM (
  SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(
      `json_col`,
      CONCAT('$[',
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
          JSON_SEARCH(
            `json_col`,
            'one',
            @`id_search`,
            NULL,
            '$[*].connection_id'
          ),
        '[^0-9]',
        ''
      ),
      ']')
    ) `con_json`
  FROM
    `your_table`
) `jd`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=248dc5f93a94694543ab95cad762be72).